# Nullity of a composite linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the problem. I know that I am going to use the rank-nullity theorem, but I am still figuring how to start and prove this:

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $f:V \rightarrow W$ and $g:W \rightarrow U$ be linear transformations over $F$. Prove that

nullity ($g\circ f$) $\leq$ nullity $(g)$ + nullity $(f)$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using Null $\,f=\dim\ker f\;$ , rank$\,f=\dim\text{Im}\,f\;$ , we have:

$$g\circ f:V\to U\implies \dim\ker (g\circ f)+\dim\text{Im}(g\circ f)=\dim V=\dim\ker f+\dim\text{Im}\,f\le$$

$$\le\dim\ker f+\dim W=\dim\ker f+\dim\ker g+\dim\text{Im}\,g$$

Take it from here.

Comment: From here dim Im ($g\circ f$) $\leq$ dim U also, dim Im g$\leq$ dim U.

Comment: But i cannot cancel dim U, since it was not an assumption that U is finite dimensional. @Timbuc

Comment: @mogs All you must care about that is that $\;g(W)\;,\;\;g\circ f(V)\;$ are finite dimensional. They both live in $\;U\;$ , which can be as infinite dimensioanl as it desires, we don't care. Remember that a linear trasnformation *cannot* increase dimension. At most it keeps it the same.

Comment: sorry, can I have more hints @Timbuc? thanks